# how to process vector(s) to get desired output?

Tags: c++, vector

I learn C++ by myself, therefore I have some blank pages in some areas, eg. some operations on containers, names of different operations etc.
Therefore please help me out with this problem.
(I would also appreciate sending me to good resources that would help me to chose right container and methods to process them. Real implementation examples would be big help, as it's easier to get it for me this way.)

This is my first 'real' program. I made it in PHP but now rewriting to C++ as I learn it (and I can say it's more challenging).

In short, file is read and 3 different vectors are created containing corresponding elements (person's name, item's name and item's amount).
So for example (I know it's not way to assign values, its just to illustrate contents):

```
vector<string> vectorOfNames = {"Adam", "Eva", "Adam", "Adam", "Bruce"};
vector<string> vectorOfItems = {"Apple", "Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Melon"};
vector<int> vectorOfAmount = {1, 9, 2, 4, 1};
```

Now, I want to represent it (by person and item) and count (by amount) those vectors, eg. to print something like:

```
All persons:
Adam
Eva
Bruce

All items:
Apple - 10
Orange - 2
Pear - 4
Melon - 1

Adam have:
Apple - 1
Orange - 2
Pear - 4

Eva have:
Apple - 9

Bruce have:
Melon - 1
```

In PHP i used *array_keys(array_flip())* to get unique names and items.
In C++ i found something like this:

```
vector< string >::iterator r , w ;

set< string > tmpset ;

for( r = vectorOfNames.begin() , w = vectorOfNames.begin() ; r != vectorOfNames.end() ; ++r )
{
    if( tmpset.insert( *r ).second )
    {
        *w++ = *r ;
    }
}

vectorOfNames.erase( w , vectorOfNames.end() );
```

It works well but problem is that it modifies original vectorOfNames.
Should I copy this vector to new one before applaying this or is there another approach?

As for the rest of desired processing in PHP I used *foreach* and *if* statements.
I was trying different approaches for C++ but nothing works. I'm completely lost....
Also I know that there are some functions in Boost Library, but for time being I don't want to go there, prefer to learn basics first.

On another hand, maybe i should use other container, like map or something else, to make this processing easier?

So if you still know what I mean and you did not fall asleep, please push me in right direction ;)

Comment: In C++11, `std::vector<T> v = {val1, val2, val3}` is perfectly fine. :P

Comment: @Xeo not if you're using MSVC :-(

Comment: For this example, why not stick with a couple of simple maps.  std::map<std::string,std::string> user_items; //key is user name  std::map<std::string,float> item_cost;  //key is item name

Comment: yes, after banging head into the wall every time i tried to 'hack' it some way, i thought that maybe another container would be better, thx, will give a try to map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step, i.e., getting all unique names in a `std::vector<std::string>` I would probably do like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> tmp(original);
std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
std::unique_copy(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(),
                 std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

An alternative solution could use an auxiliary `std::set<std::string>` but wouldn't print the names in sorted order:

```
std::set<std::string> mark;
std::copy_if(original.begin(), original.end(),
             [&](std::string const& value) { return mark.insert(value); });
```

(making use of C++ 2011 features)

The other operations don't directly map easily to the way C++ algorithms work. To deal with these I would probably use a different data layout, e.g., storing the data in a `std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string, int> >` rather than three separate vectors.

Comment: Not really need to sort results, could be in order as they appear, but it might be nice addition. Will check what the heck std::tuple is and will give it a try (yes, im a newbie). Thanks!

Comment: Well, when using `std::unique_copy()` you need to have identical elements next to each other which is achieved by `std::sort()`ing: it copies one element for each sequence of identical elements. That is the sequence `Alice, Alice, Bob, Alice` would produce `Alice, Bob, Alice` without sorting.

Comment: Thanks for extra explanations. You are very helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

This stays close to your original approach:

```
vector< string > vs;
vs.resize(vectorOfNames.size()); // more efficient if we already know the size

set< string > tmpset ;

vector< string >::const_iterator r;
for( r = vectorOfNames.begin() ; r != vectorOfNames.end() ; ++r )
{
    if( tmpset.insert( *r ).second )
    {
        vs.push_back(*r);
    }
}
```

However, it uses an auxiliary vector to store the new names, so you don't need to modify the original vector. To guarantee that you don't actually modify the vector, this approach uses a const_iterator rather than an iterator.